# get native type size from c#

Tags: c#, c++, swig

I wrapped some c++ classes using swig to c#.

There are some methods that getting as argument the size of a type(any type could pass as the parameter).

My question is how can I get the size of the c++ object with my c# code?

Comment: Just to understand, your C++ code needs the size of the C# object being passed into it? Or is it the other way around, C# needs to know the size of the value that C++ is returning?

Comment: get size in c++ and return it in c#?

Comment: Only a C++ compiler can ever determine the size of an object.  And only the *exact* same C++ compiler using the *exact* same compile options.  Also the core reason that only such a C++ compiler can ever properly create the object, you have no shot at it in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike C++, getting an object's size in .NET is always a runtime operation. [`Marshal.SizeOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/5s4920fa.aspx) calls do not get translated into compile-time constants in the same way that C++'s [`sizeof`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4s7x1k91.aspx) operator does. At runtime, .NET would require a .NET object that it could reflect across, and that object must be defined correctly using attributes like [`StructLayout`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.aspx).

So you've got two options:

1. Define a .NET version of your C++ object and use `Marshal.SizeOf`. You don't need to use the .NET object for anything. It's just there to allow you to determine the size. Of course, if you mess up that object, or if they get out of sync because of evolution, you're gonna have a bad time.
2. Expose a new method from the C++ that just returns `sizeof(MyCppObject)`. This is probably the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to get the size of a native type at runtime - there is no type information.

You'll probably want to pass the size from the native side, where it can be determined statically. Just add a `getSize` method to your objects or something.